# Javascript not running on chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to show image selected by user control in an Image Box. For doing so I am using JavaScript. It's running fine on IE but on chrome it's not working.

My Javascript code is

```
var ShowPreview = function (event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        var output = document.getElementById('Img_CreateUser');
        output.src = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

My HTML code is

```
<asp:Image ID="Img_CreateUser" runat="server"/>

            <input type="file" name="Upload_CreateUser" id="Upload_CreateUser" onchange="ShowPreview(event);" />
            <%--<asp:FileUpload ID="Upload_CreateUser" runat="server" />--%>
```

Comment: Working fine... https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/2s2aka65/

Comment: @Rayon It's working fine on IE but i don't know why it's not working on chrome on my machine.

Comment: Tested on Chrome _Version 50.0.2661.94 m_

Comment: Check the message in console in Chrome (F12). Post a screenshot of the error here.

Comment: @Jitendra Garg it's giving this error "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" but i have changed my jquery file then why is it picking up $....????

Comment: Jquery should be loaded at the head of your document

Comment: @Konst Thanks..It's working

Comment: @Konst Can i use this javascriprt for my asp file upload control because now i'm using normal HTML control...???

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell for sure from this snippet but I think that at the time the script is running the DOM is not yet loaded (and maybe different browsers respond differently), so you should try to run your JS code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //your code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> it's giving this error "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" but i
>   have changed my jquery file then why is it picking up $....????

Sounds like you have script depending on jquery running before jquery is included.
Are you including jquery in your footer? If so make sure any scripts that rely on jquery are below the jquery include.

If you have script errors then you cannot guarantee that your javascript above will work, fix the other errors and you may find it works just fine.